# Laravel - hacer un pluck de todas las relaciones a partir de una relacion polimorfica

Tags: laravel, eloquent, polimorfismo

tengo un model label: que son etiquetas de otros modelos, en mi caso : prodcutos y servicios.

Ejemplo:

Tengo la etiqueta : `barato`.

En mi relacion polimorfica digamos que el label `barato` me trae **2 productos** y **1 servicio**, es decir, hay 2 productos que tienen la etiqueta barato y un producto.

Mi quey seria la siguiente:

```
$labels = Label::where('name','barato'])->with(['services','products'])->get();
```

Vale, en este punto tengo una coleccion de etiquetas:

Como puedo hacer para obtener con `pluck` un array conformado por todos los modelos relacionados con este polimorfismo? es decir un array ya formado con servicios y productos (sin indice `n=>[]`) para devolverlo en json ya que lo que me interesa es el resultado no las etiquetas.

---

Pretendo obtener un **array** cargado de todas las relaciones con las etiquetas obtenidas en la relacion, algo como array_merge del conjunto de relaciones, de esto:

```
  #relations: array:2 [▼
    "services" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#608 ▼
      #items: array:1 [▶]
    }
    "products" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1227 ▼
      #items: array:1 [▶]
    }
  ]
```

Como si recorriera cada tipo de relacion  y por cada una lo recorriera de nuevo para obtener un array de un nivel con todas ellas.

He probado con esto:

```
$plucked = $labels->pluck('services','products')
```

Pero no funciona como deberia.

Comment: Coloca una muestra de la salida que esperas

Comment: @BetaM he editado la pregunta, gracias.